# Why do I have a missing column in my datagrid view table?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, .net-2.0

I have a Datagrid view and 1 column is missing even though it is present inside the database

this is my DGV

[image]

and this is my table in the database

[image]

i am unsure why the model column is missing but I am sure that I did have it inserted in MySQL

here is my code for adding data to the database

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into inventory.vehicle(platenumber,brand,model,yearmodel,regdate,exdate,odometer) values(@platenumber, @brand, @model,@yearmodel, @regdate, @exdate,@odometer)", conn);

     cmd.Parameters.Add("@platenumber", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = pnumber.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@brand", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 60).Value = brand.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@model", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = model.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@yearmodel", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = yearmodel.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@regdate", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = datereg.MinDate;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@exdate", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = regexp.MinDate;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@odometer", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = odometer.Text;



     int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     if (i != 0)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Success");
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Fail");
     }

     this.Close();
```

this is the function that populates my datagrid

```
 private void PopulateDataGrid()
        {

            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();

            cmd.CommandText = "select id,platenumber,brand,model,yearmodel,regdate,exdate,odometer from vehicle";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dataAdapter.Fill(datatable);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;

        }
```

Comment: How is the grid getting filled with the data from the DB? Is the code manually creating columns in the grid? Show the code that sets the grids data.

Comment: i have a datagrid populating function that gets called when the form loads

Comment: Is the code “manually” adding the columns to the grid?

Comment: Is the model column in the datatable?